# Cleanly talking to worker processes made with Node's child_process.fork()

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing

I'm forking many identical worker processes which are to be told filenames to process.

All of the worker_process examples I can find show the parent listening to just one worker.  Something like:

```
var cp = require('child_process');

worker = cp.fork('my_worker.js');

worker.on( 'message', function(msg) {
    console.log( 'Parent got message: ' + msg.text );
});
```

My question: If I want to spawn 8 workers, do I need 8 "worker.on" calls to set up 8 different listeners?  It seems weird that the listener is on the childProcess object returned by the call to `fork`.  There's one parent so you'd think it would be receiving all messages from the workers and a listener set with process.on would work, but it doesn't.

```
process.on( 'message', function(msg) {
        console.log( 'I never get called' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to globally listen to all messages from all children.  So, I tie a listener to each child process, as I originally suspected I'd have to.

But, it doesn't end up being that messy because I use closures.

So, my loop to spawn all the children looks like:

```
// Fork all workers
var workers = []

for ( i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++ ) {

    worker = cp.fork( __dirname + '/../worker.js', [i] );

    worker.on( 'message', make_message_processor(i) );

    worker.on('error', function( err ) {
        console.error( 'Worker: Something bad happened: ' + err );
    });

    workers.push( worker );

}
```

This ties a unique closed instance of the make_message_process function to each worker's messages.

That function looks like:

```
// Create message processing function for each worker
function make_message_processor( id ) {

    var local_id = id;  // this gets enclosed

    return function ( msg ) {
        //console.log('master: got message:', msg.message);
        switch ( msg.message ) {
            case 'give_me_another':
                console.log( 'master: ' + local_id + ' has asked for a job.' );
                next( local_id );
                break;
            case 'error':
                console.log( 'master: got error from worker process' );
                break;
            case 'default':
                console.log( 'master: got unknown message' );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Full code at https://github.com/bitwombat/parallel-uglifyjs